# Is it possible to customize a Smart Capture form's look and feel?

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, cloudpage

I can't seem to track down any information on how to customize the look and feel of a Smart Capture form.  Initially I created the form, took the code from the landing page, styled it as necessary, and then created a new Landing Page in Cloud Pages with the styled HTML.

The form works, in that it will submit a user to the Data Extension.  However I don't see the form as a Smart Capture entry to build into a Journey.

What gives?  Am I missing something here?

Comment: It doesn't makes sense to use the cloud page as an entry for the journey. You need to build an email template to deliver this page URL to your audience and then update DE with changes (As you are already doing). Later use that DE as an Entry point for the Journey.

Comment: Secondly your question title and summary are not in sync. I could have skipped the question just by reading the title.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.  

I created a "Smart Capture" form using Cloud Pages, but I can't seem to add the styling to match my website.  This is what I'm trying to discover.  Not sure how the title and content are out of sync...?

Comment: I think I read it wrong. I thought you were trying to use this form in the journey builder, but this is more about styling the smart capture form. I always use the microsites for building the pages. Let me check on this.

Answer (score 2):

I recently did this, and there's a not-well documented limitation on smart capture currently.

Only smart capture forms created in the **classic** cloud page editor (i.e. not the one that resembles content builder), will be usable as a journey entry. This however, works flawlessly with injections happening close to immediately.

You need to first create the smart capture form, then create the entry event.

In content builder there are many options to style the forms look & feel.
However, these options **are not** available in the classic editor though.

[image]

You might be able to style it using CSS, but it would require that you publish the form and then retrieve the classes and/or field types, and then specifically style it based on that. Hope this helps.

```
<div class="smartcapture-controls" style="position: relative; height: 295px;">
<div class="smartcapture-control" style="position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 55px; width: 249px; height: 80px;">
    <label class="activefield-label">SubscriberKey</label>
        <input type="text" class="stretchy" name="SubscriberKey" required="required" title="Please fill out this field." tabindex="1">
</div>
<div class="smartcapture-control" style="position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 135px; width: 249px; height: 80px;">
    <label class="activefield-label">EmailAddress</label>
        <input type="email" class="stretchy" name="EmailAddress" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$" title="Please fill out this field." tabindex="2">
</div>
<div class="smartcapture-control" style="position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 215px; width: 249px; height: 80px;">
    <label class="activefield-label">FirstName</label>
        <input type="text" class="stretchy" name="FirstName" title="Please fill out this field." tabindex="3">
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="SubmitDate" name="SubmitDate" value="3/7/2017 1:23:48 AM">
```

Comment: Kenneth, are you saying build the smart capture form in classic and then style it in content builder?

Comment: Regardless of editor you would need to use HTML to style it - ideally by referencing classes in your CSS :) the editors doesn't allow for much styling out-of-the-box imo.

Comment: I don't follow; my apologies.  I did style the smart capture form using HTML, but not in the UI. I can't seem to figure out how to externally styled code back into the UI and have it work as a Smart Capture Entry into a Journey.  This is the disconnect.

Comment: Hey george. First things first. Regardless of styling, the smart capture you should be able to create and use as entry event - but it requires that you've used the classic editor. I'll update my answer with an image to reflect this,

Comment: Hi again george - so, essentially, what you are trying to do cannot be done at the moment (to my knowledge). The classic smart capture forms does not display the HTML component of the form in the same way that content builder does. It would in theory be possible to style this with CSS, but it will require a bit more work. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Per Kenneth's answer above, it unfortunately looks like we have to go down the route of CSS.  It's a hassle, but is the only way at this that we can make it work.

Sadly we have to change a field type from Boolean to Text to facilitate a drop-down "Yes/No" instead of a simple check-box for "Yes" (True).